# to get max number after concatenation in list

Tags: python

The list of integers is given. We need to sort this list to get max number after concatenation.

For example, we have

```
[4, 94, 9, 14, 1]
```

It must be sorted like

```
[9, 94, 4, 14, 1]
```

and give the number `9944141`.

Comment: What kind of sorting is this? Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried.

Comment: This would be a good question just if you add the code that you have tried so far!

Comment: @Tichodroma It should be sorted in a way that after concatenation of the list, you'll have the maximum number.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes, that is written. But would you call this "sorting"? it is an algorithm question.

Comment: @l4mpi This is *not* trivial at all. I find this problem very interesting. And I upvoted.

Comment: Also the question is *very very* clear. I don't know why people are voting to close.

Comment: @l4mpi If you understand the question, you'll understand why your answer **doesn't** work. Please try to understand what OP wants before attempt to answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun right, my 5-second solution didn't work for more complex examples than the one given by OP. It's still not a hard problem; you'll just have to take the decimal length of the numbers into account. Sadly doesn't fit into a one-liner anymore. And without any specific restrictions (e.g. number of inputs, performance requirements) the answer space is simply too huge - e.g. is it acceptable to brute force it? If the input is small, that would be the most readable solution.

Comment: @l4mpi The trivial solution would be checking all permutations and pick the one that maximize the number, but this solution is O(n!). The best solution is implementing your own comparator, and pass it to `sorted` method, I guess..

Comment: @Dennis Are you interested in the "sorted" list or just in the maximum value?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I fail to see how writing a comparator function for this is not trivial - take the number with less digits, truncate the other number to the same amount of digits, compare; if equal, recursively compare to the truncated rest.

Comment: @l4mpi: Even if the final comparator is simple, deriving what it should look like and proving that it works isn't so simple. You seem remarkably overeager to declare that it's simple and provide not-quite-working solutions.

Comment: @user2357112 everybody else seems remarkably overeager to solve OPs homework and upvote a question that amounts to nothing more than an assignment dump, because they think the assignment is moderately interesting. People interested in those "interesting" problems should visit CodeGolf.SE or any of the other thousands of programming puzzle sites, but i was under the impression that SO has quality standards which should be enforced regardless of the copypasted assignment being interesting or not.

Comment: @l4mpi: Yeah, it looks like an assignment dump. Arguably, it should be closed, although if the answer doesn't yet exist on SO, it may be worth cleaning up the question and answering it for the benefit of future people who might have non-homework reasons to want this problem solved. That doesn't mean you should declare it trivial, or keep declaring it trivial after you get it wrong twice.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't believe it could ever benefit somebody who is not here for an easy solution to their assignment, but whatever. Also, where did I get it wrong twice? My first 5-second one liner was wrong because I didn't take more than those 5 seconds to think about the corner cases, and I'll agree that the compare function by dlask is more elegant than the one described by me, but mine should give the same result.

Comment: @l4mpi: Your second one-liner was wrong pre-edit; it didn't recurse.

Comment: @user2357112 unclear, not wrong - I wrote something like "compare with the rest again", then realized that this could be interpreted to mean a direct comparation (which would of course be nonsensical) instead of recursively using the compare function, thus I clarified with an edit. Anyways, this is getting quite off topic. But I believe my point about this being a bad question still stands and is exemplified by OP accepting the brute force solution instead of the compare solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, but not very efficient way is:

```
import itertools

nums = [4, 94, 9, 14, 1]
max_num = 0
max_nums = None
for p in itertools.permutations(map(str, nums)):
    num = int(''.join(p))
    if num > max_num:
        max_num = num
        max_nums = p
print map(int, max_nums)
print max_num
```

Output:

```
[9, 94, 4, 14, 1]
9944141
```

Answer (score 3):

Any custom sort boils down to implementing a *comparator* which can tell you which elements go before which other elements.

In your case, you should try some simple examples to see how the comparison should work. Let `a <~ b` mean "a should come before b once sorted". Some examples:

```
9 <~ 94
89 <~ 8 (why?)
14 <~ 1
5 <~ 4
```

Based on these examples, you should write a function

```
def compare(a, b):
    # return -1 if a < b according to the rule above, 0 if they are equal and 1 otherwise
```

then you can simply call Python's sort function:

```
numlist.sort(cmp=compare)
```

(Since no code was given, and the problem sounds like an exercise, my answer is focused on providing hints rather than a full solution!)

Comment: 9 < 94 is tricky. You want 9 to appear before 94. Because 994 is bigger than 949.

Comment: Read again: `<` means "appears before". Hence the slightly nonsensical `5 < 4` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just an example, this approach doesn't scale well because of O(n!) complexity:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [4, 94, 9, 14, 1]
>>> print list(max((int("".join(p)), p) for p in itertools.permutations(str(x) for x in l))[1])
['9', '94', '4', '14', '1']
```

All permutations are found, individual items are converted to strings and concatenated, the result is converted to integer. The permutation with the highest integer value is chosen.

---

UPDATE:

If someone is interested in better performance:

```
def compare(x, y):
    sx = str(x)
    sy = str(y)
    sxy = sx + sy
    syx = sy + sx
    if sxy < syx:
        return -1
    elif sxy > syx:
        return +1
    return 0

print sorted(l, cmp=compare, reverse=True)
# It gives [9, 94, 4, 14, 1]
```

Comment: Very wise usage of permutations.

Comment: Do you have any proof that the new algorithm actually produces the right answer?

Comment: @nneonneo No math proof available. The `compare` function correctly compares two numbers, so I expect the `sorted` function to correctly make the remaining work.

Comment: I have not understood "compare" solution :( ... we get the list as argument... but in this case "compare" gets 2 integers.. ???

Comment: @Dennis Your list contains numbers. The [sort algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) work with two selected values, either preserving their order or swapping them.